# Copying from Chrome to OneNote Changes Font Style attributes

Tags: google-chrome, onenote

When I copy text from Chrome and paste it in OneNote it changes the font size from 20 to 15 and the line spacing (Line Height) from 29 to 24 although I pasted it choosing *keep source formatting*. Why?

This is how the website looks in Chrome:

[image: source text in Chrome]

Here is how it appeared when I pasted it into OneNote with "keep source formatting" option:

[image: resulting pasted text]

You notice that the font size and line height have changed to lower numbers and I don't know why.

My screen resolution is 1366×768 and scaling is set to 100%.

Comment: What is the source of the content that you are copying?

Comment: It looks that you are using the OneNote for Windows rather than OneNote Online, so this question is off-topic on this site.